# K means Clustering in R

Tags: r, data-mining, k-means

I have a data frame with given structure.

> **District Value1  Value2  Value3**
>
> X                  1200    1500    1420
>   
>  Y                  1456    1458   
>   1247 
>  Z                  1245    1689
>      1200

I used K-means function in R to cluster Value1, Value2 and Value3 but that was not enough to find out which district falls in which cluster. I want to find out the cluster each district falls in, like:

> **District:**  X          Y           Z 
>  
>   **Cluster:**  1         2           1

How do I do this in R?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should try `kmeans` and have a look at `?kmeans` (especially at the return value `cluster`):

```
df <- data.frame(District=c("X", "Y", "Z"), 
                 Value1=c(1200, 1500, 1420), 
                 Value2=c(1456, 1458, 1247),
                 Value3=c(1245, 1689, 1200))

#  df[,-1] excludes the first column (District)
km <- kmeans(df[,-1], centers=2)

km$cluster
#[1] 1 2 1
```